# Memory Leak Detectors Working Principle

Tags: c++, c, memory-leaks

How do memory leak detectors actually work? What are the underlying concepts in general? Can take C++ as the language to explain this.

Comment: So far the (address) sanitizers have not been mentioned. [This talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V2_80g0eOMc) from CppCon14 gives a good summary of how they work.

Comment: This is a question with a useful and accurate answer. Closing or deleting it will mean we loose useful information. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287899/deleted-question-too-broad

Comment: @LokiAstari: deleting it would lose information; closing it would not.

Comment: Closing would punish people (by depriving them of reputation) who spent time composing useful answers.   We should encourage well-written, useful answers like those present here.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

There are a couple of different ways that leak detectors work. You can replace the implementation of `malloc` and `free` with ones that can track more information during allocation and are not concerned with performance. This is similar to how [`dmalloc`](http://dmalloc.com/) works. In general, any address that is `malloc`'ed but not `free`'d is leaked.

The basic implementation is actually pretty simple. You just maintain a lookup table of every allocation and its line number, and remove the entry when it is freed. Then when the program is done you can list all leaked memory. The hard part is determining when and where the allocation should have been freed. This is even harder when there are multiple pointers to the same address.

In practice, you'll probably want more than just the single line number, but rather a stack trace for the lost allocations.

Another approach is how [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) works which implements an entire virtual machine to keep track of addresses and memory references and associated bookkeeping. The valgrind approach is much more expensive, but also much more effective as it can also tell you about other types of memory errors like out of bounds reads or writes.

Valgrind essentially instruments the underlying instructions and can track when a given memory address has no more references. It can do this by tracking assignments of addresses, and so it can tell you not just that a piece of memory was lost, but exactly *when* it became lost.

C++ makes things a little harder for both types of leak detectors because it adds the `new` and `delete` operators. Technically `new` can be a completely different source of memory than `malloc`. However, in practice many real C++ implementations just use `malloc` to implement `new` or have an option to use `malloc` instead of the alternate approach.

Also higher level languages like C++ tend to have alternative higher level ways of allocating memory like `std::vector` or `std::list`. A basic leak detector would report the potentially many allocations made by the higher level modes separately. That's much less useful than saying the entire container was lost.

Comment: Thanks @b4hand for descriptive answer. So, it won't be easy task to implement basic memory leak detector as what I am understanding from this.
And one doubt I got from your explanation. 
You said "Technically new can be a completely different source of memory than malloc. ". In all the scenarios, shouldn't **new** use the same heap as **malloc** uses?

Comment: The C++ standard does not specify that, but like I said, in practice most real world implementations do use the same underlying resource.

Comment: @amit1990: it's plausible that a C++ implementation might allocate memory in large chunks with malloc then implement `new` to use some sort of object pool within that block. This may be to reduce memory fragmentation as objects of the same types are usually of the same size size. To a memory debugger that only intercepts malloc, the pool becomes opaque.

Comment: @amit:Re:"won't be easy". Depends on what your end goal is, but if your goal is to create a leak detector because your development environment doesn't already have one and you just need it for debug testing then it is just a bit harder than trivial. Just create your own malloc/free implementation and have it spit out any memory still allocated when the program exits. If you are intending to use it in your end product then it becomes a bit harder to ensure it is performant and reliable.

Comment: Let's also not forget that an app can also allocate memory using OS APIs directly instead of using `malloc`/`new`, and also that STL containers support custom memory allocators (so an app could use whatever memory it wants - stack memory, a memory mapped file, etc).

Comment: @Lie Ryan.. ok, got the point. Acutally, didn't know the implementation of new. Will go through it. But ya, the idea is pretty much clear now.

Comment: @Dunk , yes, that is what I was able to perceive from this post.

Comment: @amit1990: Actually, what `new` and `malloc` do are two different things. `malloc` allocates a chunk of bytes, while `new` allocates a chunk of bytes to store an object of a certain type AND initializes the object by calling its constructor. They are not required to allocate form the same pool, and they are not required to allocate from a different pool. So you can assume neither. To add to the subject, Rationale Purify also takes care of detecting `malloc/free`, `new/delete` and `new[]/delete[]` mismatches. They instrument SOs to redirect memory management calls to their own libraries.

Answer (score 19):

Here's a [published technical paper on how our CheckPointer tool works.](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Company/Publications/CheckPointer.pdf)

Fundamentally it tracks the lifetimes of all values (heap and stack), and their sizes according their types as defined by the language.  This allows CheckPointer to find not only leaks, but out-of-array bound accesses, even for arrays in the stack, which valgrind won't do.

In particular, it analyzes the source code to find all pointer uses.
(This is quite the task just by itself).

It keeps track of pointer meta data for each pointer, consisting of

- A reference to the object meta data for the heap-allocated object or global or local variable orfunction pointed to by the pointer and
- The address range of the (sub)object of the object that the pointer may currently access. This may be smaller than the address range of the
  whole object; e.g. if you take the address of a struct member, the instrumented source code will only allow access to that member when using the resulting pointer.

It also tracks the kind and location of each object, i.e. whether
it is a function, a global, thread-local or local variable, heap-allocated memory, or a string literal constant:

- The address range of the object that may be safely accessed, and
- For each pointer stored in the heap-allocated object or variable, a reference to the pointer metadata for that pointer.

All this tracking is accomplished by transforming the original program source, into a program which does what the original program does, and interleaves various meta-data checking or updating routines.   The resulting program is compiled and run.   Where a meta-data check fails at runtime, a backtrace is provided with a report of the type of failure (invalid pointer, pointer outside valid bounds, ...)

Comment: Downvoted, because the answer would be, if hte link should go down, be not really informative.

Comment: The link site has existed longer than StackOverflow by more than 10 years; it isn't likely to go away.  And the link leads to a *truly* informative answer.  The purpose of the web and hyperlinks is to avoid copying the entire web into Stackoverflow.  Get some perspective, people.

Comment: I aggree to that the linke leads to a good answer. But the point is: without the link it not that usefull. And the rule about it is clear. (without any need for perspectives). So what prevents you from just summarize the information contained in the link by a little more in depp detail?

Comment: I have added more detail. I observe that the question of "how much deep detail" is necessary is a function of the reader; you can't satisfy everybody. Thus a link to "the rest of the detail".

Comment: @Zaibis without the link you can still know to Google "Ira Baxter CheckPointer" or "Semantic Designs CheckPointer"

Comment: The software your company produces is not free (either sense) right? (not a criticism, just want to know)

Comment: Semantic Designs is a commercial software engineering tools company.  The software is not free, correct.   The evaluation versions run for free, often with some size limitations.  Many of them will work well enough for students, assuming they are working on student-sized projects.

Answer (score 8):

This is tagged C and C++ and no operating system is mentioned. This answer is for Windows.

### C

Windows has the concept of virtual memory. Any memory a process can get is virtual memory. This is done through [VirtualAlloc() [MSDN]](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366887%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). You can imagine the leak detector to put a breakpoint on that function and whenever it is called, it gets the callstack and saves it somewhere. Then it can do similar for [VirtualFree()[MSDN]](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366892%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

The difference can then be identified and shown along with the callstacks that have been saved.

### C++

C++ has a different concept: it takes the large 64kb blocks which it gets from VirtualAlloc() and splits it into smaller pieces, called the Heap. The C++ heap manager comes from Microsoft and offers new methods [HeapAlloc() [MSDN]](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366597%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [HeapFree()[MSDN]](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366701%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Then, you could do the same as before, but actually, that feature is already built-in. Microsoft's [GFlags [MSDN]](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff549557%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) tool can enable the tracking:

[image: Screenshot: GFlags enabled for Notepad]

In this case it will save up to 50 MB of callstack information for C++ heap manager calls.

Since that settings can also be enabled via the Windows Registry, a memory leak detector can make use of it easily.

### General concept

As you can see, the general concept is to keep track of allocations and deallocations, compare them and show the callstacks of the difference.

Comment: The details about how memory is allocated from the operating system is implementation dependent. The good info here is probably only true for Microsoft's compiler and only with the current default compiler flags. AFAICT, neither C or C++ standard specifies how memory should be allocated from the OS. So be careful if you need to make use of this in a program that needs to be portable.

Comment: 1. You aren't required to use VirtualAlloc in C. There are still `malloc` and `free` which most programs use (indeed, using VirtualAlloc directly is rare). 2. The C++ memory manager is the same thing. 3. HeapAlloc et al. are not C++-specific but can be used in C (and are probably how `malloc` is implemented).

Comment: *Plus 9*?? Man, blame my eyes, I just can't see +9